# How do I fetch specific data from a JSON in java using getString() function

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get weather portion from the JSON file but it shows an exception.

This is my code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
          String weather =  jsonObject.getString("weather");
           Log.i("Contents of URL", weather);
           //Log.i("Contents of URL", String.valueOf(jsonObject));  When I log this the whole JSON is printed to the console as expected.
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
        }
```

This is the JSON file from which this data is extracted.

```
{"message":"","cod":"200","city_id":4887398,"calctime":0.0863,"cnt":4,"list":[{"main":{"temp":268.987,"temp_min":268.987,"temp_max":268.987,"pressure":1001.11,"sea_level":1024.68,"grnd_level":1001.11,"humidity":100},"wind":{"speed":5.06,"deg":291.002},"clouds":{"all":48},"**weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}]**,"dt":1485703465},{"main":{"temp":268.097,"temp_min":268.097,"temp_max":268.097,"pressure":1003.57,"sea_level":1027.08,"grnd_level":1003.57,"humidity":100},"wind":{"speed":8.56,"deg":314.007},"clouds":{"all":44},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"dt":1485730032},{"main":{"temp":266.787,"temp_min":266.787,"temp_max":266.787,"pressure":1005.73,"sea_level":1029.63,"grnd_level":1005.73,"humidity":100},"wind":{"speed":6.79,"deg":316.012},"clouds":{"all":0},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01n"}],"dt":1485755383},{"main":{"temp":263.64,"pressure":1015,"humidity":57,"temp_min":262.15,"temp_max":265.15},"wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":280},"clouds":{"all":1},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"dt":1485780512}]}
```

What I want is the weather information which is not printed.Instead one of the **exception** is printed.
What do I do to fetch only the weather information from the JSON?

Comment: Have you tried to format the given JSON, you need to fix your JSON format.  After you fix your JSON, the better way to parse your JSON would be to use https://github.com/google/gson or related library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
     String str = "{\n" + 
            "  \"message\": \"\",\n" + 
            "  \"cod\": \"200\",\n" + 
            "  \"city_id\": 4887398,\n" + 
            "  \"calctime\": 0.0863,\n" + 
            "  \"cnt\": 4,\n" + 
            "  \"list\": [\n" + 
            "    {\n" + 
            "      \"main\": {\n" + 
            "        \"temp\": 268.987,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_min\": 268.987,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_max\": 268.987,\n" + 
            "        \"pressure\": 1001.11,\n" + 
            "        \"sea_level\": 1024.68,\n" + 
            "        \"grnd_level\": 1001.11,\n" + 
            "        \"humidity\": 100\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"wind\": {\n" + 
            "        \"speed\": 5.06,\n" + 
            "        \"deg\": 291.002\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"clouds\": {\n" + 
            "        \"all\": 48\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"weather\": [\n" + 
            "        {\n" + 
            "          \"id\": 802,\n" + 
            "          \"main\": \"Clouds\",\n" + 
            "          \"description\": \"scattered clouds\",\n" + 
            "          \"icon\": \"03d\"\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "      ],\n" + 
            "      \"dt\": 1485703465\n" + 
            "    },\n" + 
            "    {\n" + 
            "      \"main\": {\n" + 
            "        \"temp\": 268.097,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_min\": 268.097,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_max\": 268.097,\n" + 
            "        \"pressure\": 1003.57,\n" + 
            "        \"sea_level\": 1027.08,\n" + 
            "        \"grnd_level\": 1003.57,\n" + 
            "        \"humidity\": 100\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"wind\": {\n" + 
            "        \"speed\": 8.56,\n" + 
            "        \"deg\": 314.007\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"clouds\": {\n" + 
            "        \"all\": 44\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"weather\": [\n" + 
            "        {\n" + 
            "          \"id\": 802,\n" + 
            "          \"main\": \"Clouds\",\n" + 
            "          \"description\": \"scattered clouds\",\n" + 
            "          \"icon\": \"03d\"\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "      ],\n" + 
            "      \"dt\": 1485730032\n" + 
            "    },\n" + 
            "    {\n" + 
            "      \"main\": {\n" + 
            "        \"temp\": 266.787,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_min\": 266.787,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_max\": 266.787,\n" + 
            "        \"pressure\": 1005.73,\n" + 
            "        \"sea_level\": 1029.63,\n" + 
            "        \"grnd_level\": 1005.73,\n" + 
            "        \"humidity\": 100\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"wind\": {\n" + 
            "        \"speed\": 6.79,\n" + 
            "        \"deg\": 316.012\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"clouds\": {\n" + 
            "        \"all\": 0\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"weather\": [\n" + 
            "        {\n" + 
            "          \"id\": 800,\n" + 
            "          \"main\": \"Clear\",\n" + 
            "          \"description\": \"Sky is Clear\",\n" + 
            "          \"icon\": \"01n\"\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "      ],\n" + 
            "      \"dt\": 1485755383\n" + 
            "    },\n" + 
            "    {\n" + 
            "      \"main\": {\n" + 
            "        \"temp\": 263.64,\n" + 
            "        \"pressure\": 1015,\n" + 
            "        \"humidity\": 57,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_min\": 262.15,\n" + 
            "        \"temp_max\": 265.15\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"wind\": {\n" + 
            "        \"speed\": 2.6,\n" + 
            "        \"deg\": 280\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"clouds\": {\n" + 
            "        \"all\": 1\n" + 
            "      },\n" + 
            "      \"weather\": [\n" + 
            "        {\n" + 
            "          \"id\": 800,\n" + 
            "          \"main\": \"Clear\",\n" + 
            "          \"description\": \"sky is clear\",\n" + 
            "          \"icon\": \"01n\"\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "      ],\n" + 
            "      \"dt\": 1485780512\n" + 
            "    }\n" + 
            "  ]\n" + 
            "}";
    
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);        
    JSONArray listArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
    JSONObject weatherObj = new JSONObject();
    for (int i=0; i < listArray.length(); i++) {
        weatherObj = listArray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
    System.out.println(weatherObj.getString("weather"));
    
Output : [{"icon":"01n","description":"sky is clear","main":"Clear","id":800}]
```

Comment: How do I get  only  "main": "Clouds","description": "scattered clouds" from all the objects from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The json you are receiving has weather as a key inside of another key:

```
{
  "message": "",
  "cod": "200",
  "city_id": 4887398,
  "calctime": 0.0863,
  "cnt": 4,
  "list": [
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 268.987,
        "temp_min": 268.987,
        "temp_max": 268.987,
        "pressure": 1001.11,
        "sea_level": 1024.68,
        "grnd_level": 1001.11,
        "humidity": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 5.06,
        "deg": 291.002
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 48
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03d"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485703465
    },
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 268.097,
        "temp_min": 268.097,
        "temp_max": 268.097,
        "pressure": 1003.57,
        "sea_level": 1027.08,
        "grnd_level": 1003.57,
        "humidity": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 8.56,
        "deg": 314.007
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 44
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03d"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485730032
    },
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 266.787,
        "temp_min": 266.787,
        "temp_max": 266.787,
        "pressure": 1005.73,
        "sea_level": 1029.63,
        "grnd_level": 1005.73,
        "humidity": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 6.79,
        "deg": 316.012
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "Sky is Clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485755383
    },
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 263.64,
        "pressure": 1015,
        "humidity": 57,
        "temp_min": 262.15,
        "temp_max": 265.15
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 2.6,
        "deg": 280
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 1
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "sky is clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485780512
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see clearly that you need to access the list key and then the weather key to get the data.

Pay attention that list is a ***JSONArray***.